# Return list of errors vs. using delegate function

Tags: javascript, events, delegates

I have a Javascript class that performs a number of validity checks using the data provided to the class. I am trying to figure out the best way to create a validate() function which would return one error or multiple errors. One way would be to return an array of errors. Another way would be to pass a delegate to the function which would fire whenever any error occurs. Another way would be to create an event that would be fired whenever any error occurs. Out of these 3, which would be the most appropriate for what I am trying to accomplish?

Returning an array makes the interface a bit complex. On the other hand, if I use a delegate or event, then the delegate function/event code could be a bit complex as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to be a user of your interface, then I'd like to be able to subscribe to certain subsets or levels of errors spat out from the object.

For example, lots of loggers out there act on the notion of a logging level (Verbose, Warning, or Error for example). You could provide an interface where your object is actually logging/pushing notifications for each type of error it encounters, but you expose different callbacks for each type of message. So your users will be able to decide what to listen to.

To answer your question though, I'd like to see all errors rather than just one. And I'd say keep them coming until **I** unsubscribe from the notifications.

Comment: Are you saying use events then?